# How to create a constant numeration of ID (indexing) in an attribute table (ArcMap)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, indexing

Is it possible to create a constant indexing (as a numbers) in an attribute table of the theme with many objects that manner that it will remain (will not change) during update of this theme? 
I found the instrument “Drop Index (Coverage)”, but it seems that it works only with ArcInfo license. Is it possible to create “constant” numeration of ID in ArcMap?

Comment: I would forget about Drop Index (Coverage) because that is only available with the old ArcInfo Workstation i.e. not the ArcMap application of ArcGIS for Desktop.  In any event I think you are after some type of Globally Unique Identifier (GUID) generator.

Answer (score 5):

What you appear to be asking about here is how to create a Globally Unique Identifier (GUID).

The Production Mapping extension to ArcGIS for Desktop has a [Populate GUID](http://help.arcgis.com/en%20/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0103000000w5000000) tool for this but if you do not have access to an ArcInfo level license then I am assuming it unlikely that you have Production Mapping.

Fortunately, Eagle Information Mapping have described a technique for doing this using ArcMap, Calculate Field and the uuid module of Python in their [blog](http://eaglemap.com/blog/bid/45555/How-to-Generate-GUIDs-in-ArcMap).

In addition, you may want to vote for the ArcGIS Idea to have a [GUID Generator](https://esri.secure.force.com/ideaView?id=08730000000btE0AAI) added to ArcGIS for Desktop (and/or ArcGIS Professional).

Comment: Thank you very mutch!
I tried to use the description in the blog that you gave me. But I can’t understand, they wrote about “GUID” and “String” data type of new fields that they created in Arcmap:
“So let’s get to it. Suppose we have a polyline feature class containing pipeline features; let’s call it Raw Pipeline Polylines. We’ll add two fields to our feature class: LineGUID and StringGUID. LineGUID has a data type of GUID; StringGUID has a data type of String, with Length = 38.”

Comment: But there are no such types of a new field in ArcMap (only: Short Integer, Long Integer, Float, Double, Text and Date). 
So, I maybe I understood them incorrectly? What kind of type of new fileds I should select?

Comment: Guid data types are available for feature classes in file geodatabases but not for shapefiles (I just tested at 10.2).  I would recommend that you use a file geodatabase as soon as you start having more than basic GIS requirements to meet.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in calculate field this expression: [OBJECTID] + 1

Comment: This answer needs more details to be useful. Can you edit your answer to provide a bit more information on how you intended the original poster to apply your instructions. Menu selection, etc?

Comment: I think this would have been better as a Comment than an Answer.  Although it could still be expanded upon to become a useful Answer by using the edit button.

Comment: carfog81 gave a good advice, very simple way, but it works )) I I calculated by Field Calculator in a new Double field the expression: FID (index that ArcMap gave to the at. table) + 1, and recieved the field of constant numeration.

Comment: PolyGeo - thank you very much for the explanation, I will try it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally I use for indexing two instruments:

1)At first I sort my fields as I want by Sort tool (Data Management – General), that gives me a new theme with sorted attributes and a default index field FID.

2)And then I create a new Double Field “My_id” where I calculate by Field Calculator “FID+1” – as a result I receive a constant numeration of my attributes.